# I am now learning how to work with arrays and I'm struggling with my assigment to make a multiplication table and get the average

Tags: c, arrays

The assignment consist of creating a multiplication table where the product of the user inputted multiplicand and multiplier is stored in an array called `myArray[12]`. Then the Average function has to have two parameters (Array and multiplier), which returns the average of the elements in the array called `myArray`. I am also confused as to how make "average" a separate function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int num, i = 0, multiplier;
    int myArray[12] = {};
    double average; 

    printf("\n Enter a multiplicand: \n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    printf("\n Enter the multiplier: \n");
    scanf("%d", &multiplier);

    for(i=1; i <= multiplier; ++i){
        printf("%d * %d = %d \n", num, i, num*i);
    }

    myArray[i] = myArray[i] + num * 1;
    average = myArray[i] / multiplier;
    printf("%f\n", average);

    return;
}
```

Comment: If you are already storing the product in the array first, then what is the point of passing a multiplier for array function?

Comment: @SourishMukherjee It appears that `multiplier` is actually the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping `i` from 1 to `multiplier`, so when you exit that loop, `i` will be equal to `multiplier + 1`. Then you set `myArray[i]`, but `myArray` is only defined to have 12 elements, so something bad will happen if `i` is >= 12 at this point.

I think that what you're trying to do is:

- Ask the user for two numbers, `num` and `multiplier`.
- Calculate `i * num` for `i` values from 1 to `multiplier`.
- Average those numbers.

Note: I think you have the roles of `num` and `multiplier` reversed in your example, but I'm using your terminology.

So you have a few things wrong here. First, you need to allocate enough space for to hold the values you're generating.

```
int *myArray = calloc(multiplier, sizeof (int));
```

Now `myArray` points to an `int` array of `multiplier` elements.

Next, you should move the assignment to `myArray[i]` inside of the loop. I think you just want to set it to `i * num`.

Finally, to calculate the average, you have to total up all the values in `myArray` and divide by `multiplier`. But you said you have to write this as a function. This function will have to take:

1. A pointer to the start of the array of values, which is `myArray`.
2. The number of values in the array, which is `multiplier`.

These are the two parameters that you were asked to use. You should define the function like this:

```
double calculate_average(int *array, int length) {
    // Loop i from 0 to length here to add up array values,
    // then divide by length.
}
```

Then in `main`:

```
double average = calculate_average(myArray, multiplier);
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! It really helps since I am still learning. I adjusted my code with your suggestions but I seem to be having trouble with the average function.

Comment: Quick question. If length = 1, how many times will your "average" loop execute? Also, `*array` is always the first element of the array. If you want the i-th element you need `array[i]` or `*(array + i)` (both are the same). You want to total all the values in the array and then divide that total by `length` to find the average. You also have to return the average from the function; it looks like you're returning nothing. (Is the compiler emitting warnings?)